# How to get Python 3 with Enthought Canopy installed?

Tags: enthought

When Enthought Canopy Express is downloaded and installed from `https://store.enthought.com/downloads/#default`, the Python version that gets installed is Python 2.7. Is it possible to get Python3 installed with Enthought Canopy Express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, Python 3 is not yet available with Enthought Canopy. The work to do so is well underway but no ETA has been announced.